# How to implement a client responsive upvote/downvote system with firebase functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase database and cloud functions to implement an upvote downvote system.

For the sake of responsiveness vote action also executes on the client side by a react setstate.

```
vote(id, voteValue){
    let totalVoteObj = this.props.totalVote
    //modify totalVoteObj to change a specific vote value
    //....
    this.setState({
        totalVoteObj: totalVoteObj
    })
}
```

Then when a cloud function increments the total vote count firebase listener will send newProps

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.setState({
        totalVoteObj: nextProps.totalVote
    })
}
```

However the issue with this approach is that if a user makes 2 votes real fast before the server's first response vote button will blink.

```
Expected                      What user sees on screen
initial                                 0
upvote                                  1
downvote                                0

What happens: 
initial vote state                      0
user upvotes                            1
user downvotes                          0
server responds to first user action    1
server responds to second user action   0
```

I've considered and tried few different approaches but I wasn't completely satisfied with any of the outcomes.

- Comparing votes on componentWillReceiveProps which got tricky and caused issues when multiple users vote on the same item.
- Locking user out until the response ends up making the app look less responsive.
- Tried a cloud functions solution which caused considerable lag.
- setTimeout and evaluate the vote outcome after a certain time and send a single response (which would also make sense because user shouldn't be able to make that many requests anyways because it would increase our server and database costs)

Everything works out okay unless the user spams the vote button (even if the user spams final vote value will be correct) but the clientside just appears clunky or unstable. So I just wondered if there is a "textbook" solution to deal with this using React/Redux/Firebase.

Edit: Users have unique votes, the issue happens when user keeps changing his vote within few seconds. As in spamming the buttons upvote, downvote, upvote, downvote...

Comment: in a traditional upvote/downvote system design, users are only allowed to issue one vote on each element.  Is this a unique design where users can provide multiple votes for the same item?  and if so, what are the limitations?  is it possible and allowable for someone to, say, upvote the same item 10,000 times?  and how would multiple votes from the same user be represented?

Comment: It is a unique design, I edited the post to clarify that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific problem with the flashing is the latency between client and server updates. You can fix this problem by using a throttle/debounce mechanism (like the rxjs implementation) where you wait, for example, X seconds after the last server update before publishing the updated count. So if another update comes in before that X seconds is up, you replace it and wait another X seconds before updating the view layer. Of course, if there are an infinite amount of updates you need to keep another counter Y that publishes a change if the view hasn't updated for Y seconds, so it eventually updates no matter what.

TLDR; There is no way to stop the flashing with this architecture without implementing some kind of throttle/debounce. Even reddit doesn't have super live updating and often you need to refresh the page to get an updated count.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if (this.props.totalVote !== nextProps.totalVote) { // check if changed
    totalCountObservable.next(nextProps.totalVote) // publish to observable
  }
}


// Somewhere else, subscribe to observable and throttle updates
totalCountObservable
.throttle(5000)
.subscribe(count => {
  this.setState({
    totalVoteObj: count
  })
})
```

note: this is untested pseudocode

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need to optimise for the scenario where the user upvotes and downvotes real fast? Who does that? How common is that scenario? It makes sense to make the UI feel responsive for just a single upvote and downvote, which you've already done using setState. Move onto the next feature already :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree you have a point :P I just wanted to keep the interface it as unbreakable as possible but there should be no issue as long as user votes more than once in few seconds. 

Another reason I posted was also to get an idea of an ideal voting structure which might also prevent the issue when user spams. (Since it increases the server load and eventually the server pricing!) But thanks for the advice!